File upload with React and Node.js doesn't work in production environment (Cpanel)
I've  a problem when uploading files from client-side (React.js) to the server-side (Nodejs). When I upload the image then press submit button, a loader appear and keep loading with no result (just loading - no response is sent from database).
Note:

The problem occurs only in production environement (Cpanel
deployment), in development the file upload works fine.

All other requests like editing text, change status work fine in
both (dev - prod). The problem is on the file  upload request only.

Sometimes it uploads the file (in production) but most times it keeps loading without any response.


client.js:
const updateCoverImage = async (formData)=> {
    try {
        const response = await fetch(api+"/update-cover-image/cover", {
            method: 'PATCH',
            credentials: 'include',
            mode: 'cors',
            body: formData
        }).then(response=> response.json());
        if(!response?.data) {
            throw new Error(response.message);
        }
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        return error.message;
    }
}

controller.js:
const updateCoverImage = async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const { id } = req.user;
        let { filename } = req.file;
        const { folder } = req.params;

        if (!filename) {
            return view.error(res, 400, "Please provide cover image");
        }
        filename = api_url + "assets/restaurant/" + folder + "/" + filename;
        await connectDb(async pool => {
            // get old cover image
            const [oldCoverImage] = await pool.query("SELECT cover_image FROM restaurant WHERE user_id =?", [id]);
            if (!oldCoverImage) {
                return view.error(res, 404, "Restaurant not found");
            }
            const cover_image = oldCoverImage[0].cover_image.split("/cover/")[1];
            // remove old cover image from directory
            const isFileExist = fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, astP + "restaurant/cover/" + cover_image));
            if (isFileExist) {
                deleteFile(path.join(__dirname, astP + "restaurant/cover/" + cover_image));
            }

            const [rows] = await pool.query("UPDATE restaurant SET cover_image =? WHERE user_id =?", [filename, id]);
            if (rows.affectedRows === 0) {
                return view.error(res, 404, "Restaurant not found");
            }
            return view.success(res, { message: "Cover image updated successfully" });
        })
    } catch (error) {
        // console.log(error);
        return view.error(res, 500, "An error occurred. Please try again later.");
    }
}

router.js:
router.patch("/update-cover-image/:folder", protectRouteToken, upload(astP+"restaurant/").single("image"), updateCoverImage);

multer.js:
const multer = require('multer');
const path = require("path");
const fs = require('fs');

const upload = (newPath) => {
    try {
        const storage = multer.diskStorage({
            destination: (req, file, cb) => {
                const destination = path.join(__dirname, newPath, req.params.folder || "");

                if (!fs.existsSync(destination)) {
                    fs.mkdirSync(destination);
                }

                cb(null, destination);
            },
            filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                const src = Date.now() + '-' + "welqr." + file.originalname.split(".")[file.originalname.split(".").length - 1];
                cb(null, src);
            }
        });

        const uploadFile = multer({
            storage: storage,
            limits: { fieldSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5 } // 5MB
        })
        return uploadFile;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
}

module.exports = { upload };


Have you actually verified that you are getting "no response", by checking in your browser dev tools network panel?

@C3roe I checked the browser dev tools in network panel I got request with status (pending)

@C3roe, Note that when I upload an image with small size like 20KB it uploaded successfully (after a 5s of wait). When I upload an image with size more than 300KB or more it keep loading with no response, and the request in network panel is (pending),

You specified a fieldSize of 5MB in your multer options - maybe you need to overwrite a too-low default for fileSize as well?

Thank you so much for your help! Your explanation really cleared things up for me, and the solution worked perfectly. I appreciate you taking the time to assist with this issue. You've saved me a lot of time and frustration!" @C3roe

Can you just explain what's the fieldSize ?

The maximum number of bytes allowed for any non-file parameter, as far as I can tell from the docs.
